# Locating where the jquery change comes from

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my megamenu, whenever I hover between unsorted lists I can see, in inspector, style being added `overflow:hidden` and `height`. This height causes the entire mega menu to 'jump' by about 10px. I have searched all my jquery, and I know I didn't put any such code in it, and tried finding if any of the added jquery libraries (superfish for instance) are adding it, but no luck.

Is it possible in Chrome to somehow pinpoint where this change comes from? Or in Firefox? Because something must be adding that inline style, and I have no idea what.

Comment: Post your jquery code

Comment: it's not easy. i would actually look at the rules the script defines and then grep your js files for a smoking gun. you might be able to use devtool's profile/timeline tools: layout events get connected to the stack trace in the GUI. lastly, and i mean lastly, you can clobber the style properties with a logging setter (using O.DP and a list of css property names and arguments.callee.caller), but ouch...

Comment: I am looking in FF developer and I tried recording and seeing if I'll find something there, but no luck. I'll try with Crome. 
@Hudixt: I do not have any code that controls that, that's the thing.

Comment: It's definitely an issue with superfish, just don't know why it's doing this...

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Superfish was adding the code, but the 'jump' came from my megamenu list items being set as `display:inline-block` and not `display: block` elements. Once I put them to `block`, the jump was gone.